Ubuntu 24.04 in virtual machine slow
I have a PC with Fedora 40, and I am using the app Boxes (that comes shipped with Fedora) to run a virtual machine with Ubuntu 24.04. It works fine, however, upon opening some windows or hovering the mouse over some buttons, it freezes for about 20-60 seconds before becoming responsive again. I believe this happens mainly with some gnome apps. For example, I can use FreeCAD inside the virtual machine and it is very responsive, it never freezes. However, when I switch to a terminal or the file explorer, it freezes. What could it be?
The virtual machine has 4 CPUs, 33 GB of memory and 222 GB of SSD. The host PC has 64 GB of memory, 16 CPUs and 2 TB of SSD. The display resolution on the virtual machine is 1920×1024 and in the host PC is 3840×2400.
